# Comparing 2 data frames and finding values are not in 2nd data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have 2 data frames, df1 contains set of IDs and names and df2 contains a set of IDs.

How do I compare both data frames to produce a 3rd data frame with a set of IDs and names that were not found in df2?

[image]

Comment: Just copy df1 into df3 and delete elements from df3 that exist in df2, don't try to merge or join but just remove unwanted elements. if you give a reproductible code, i can help you with

Comment: try using except

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we call an "anti-join" in SQL world: do a left join between the two frames, then filter out any records in the result where the joins matched.

The way I like to do it is:

1. If `df_2` has only the `ID` column, make a copy of the dataframe and add another dummy column: `df_2_temp = df_2.copy().assign(dummy=1)`
2. Do the left `merge()` (I'm assuming `ID` is not an index, else you would use `join()`): `df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2_temp, how="left", left_on="ID", right_on="ID")`
3. Now filter out the records where the join was successful - where there was a match between the sets - and clean up by getting rid of `dummy`: `df_3 = df_3[df_3.dummy.isna()].drop(columns="dummy")`

**Update**: it occurs to me that the `indicator` parameter of `merge()` ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#:%7E:text=indicatorbool%20or%20str,in%20both%20DataFrames.)) can obviate the need for the `dummy` column. Am leaving answer as is so that it makes the steps explicit.

Answer (score 1):

try subtracting two sets with ids and then filter on the result creating a new dataframe using append

```
lstID=['ID_0001','ID_0002','ID_0003','ID_0004','ID_0005','ID_0006','ID_0007','ID_0008','ID_0009']
lstName=['Brenda','Chloe','Jim','Ron','Eva','Winnie','Marc','Levi','Kiril']
lstID2=['ID_0003','ID_0005','ID_0006','ID_0008']
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':lstID,'Name':lstName})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':lstID2})

set1=set(df['ID'])
set2=set(df2['ID'])
result=set1-set2
print(result)

df_result=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i in result:
    df_result=df_result.append(df[df['ID']==i])
        

print(df_result.sort_values(by='ID'))
```

output:

```
    ID    Name
0  ID_0001  Brenda
1  ID_0002   Chloe
3  ID_0004     Ron
6  ID_0007    Marc
8  ID_0009   Kiril
​
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `anti_join()`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, anti_join, paste0, seq
>>> df1 = tibble(
>>>   ID=paste0("ID_000", seq(9)), 
>>>   name=["Brenda", "Choloe", "Jim", "Ron", "Eva", "Winnie", "Marc", "Levi", "Kiril"]
>>> )
>>> df1
        ID     name
  <object> <object>
0  ID_0001   Brenda
1  ID_0002   Choloe
2  ID_0003      Jim
3  ID_0004      Ron
4  ID_0005      Eva
5  ID_0006   Winnie
6  ID_0007     Marc
7  ID_0008     Levi
8  ID_0009    Kiril
>>> df2 = tibble(ID=paste0("ID_000", [3, 5, 6, 8]))
>>> anti_join(df1, df2)
        ID     name
  <object> <object>
0  ID_0001   Brenda
1  ID_0002   Choloe
3  ID_0004      Ron
6  ID_0007     Marc
8  ID_0009    Kiril
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package, which is backed by pandas and porting dplyr and related packages from R to python.